# TeX is showing the error message "missing $ inserted"

Tags: math-mode, symbols

TeX is showing the error message `missing $ inserted` from typesetting

```
\sqrt{I} = \{a \in R \mid $a^n$ \in I, \exists n\in \mathbb{N}\}
```

The outcome is attached.

[image]

Comment: in general always put whole expressions in math mode, not `$` just around individual letters.

Comment: It's also a good idea to provide a complete example.  Your whole expression is math, so should have been surrounded by a set of `$`.  TeX would have given an error before the `\sqrt` or before the `^` depending on if you had the outer `$` that you don't show or didn't use.  Overleaf echos the error, but can make it a bit hard to see the exact error message, which would have indicated one of those places in the line of text.

Answer (score 3):

use this code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsfonts}

\begin{document}
    $\sqrt{I} = \{a \in R \mid \, a^n \, \in I, \exists n\in \mathbb{N}\}$          
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note, that the `\mathbb` command requires loading the `amsfonts` or `amssymb` package.

Comment: What's the purpose of the thinspace (`\,`) between `a^n` and `\in`?

Comment: It is a small separation between the symbols, you can remove it if you wish.✌

Comment: Or the "\," you can replace them with "\quad" or "\qquad" for more space between them. ✌

Comment: @AlejandroMunozOssa the question about `\, ` was probably rhetorical. Normally one does not add a space before `\in`

Comment: For completeness: `mathtools` is a great package and I use it regularly, but it isn't needed here.

Comment: @AlejandroMunozOssa I see no reason at all for those `\,` commands. Actually I see several reasons for not adding them.